# What do I call the person who is talking in 'Jabberwocky' but isn't the narrator?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have to write a summary of the poem 'Jabberwocky' by Lewis Carroll. There is a person in it who is talking but is not the narrator. What do I call this character?

Comment: Alice didn't understand it either - all she could be sure of was that *somebody killed something*. But the only reported speech in the poem isn't from *that* "somebody" - I've always assumed it's the Jabberwock-slayer's uncle, for no particular reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The chortler is the hero's father, surely? "Beware the Jabberwock, my son ..."

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm sure Victorian uncles used *"My boy!"* and *"My son!"* at least as freely as we do today, even if I can't quite imagine a Victorian football fan shouting *"Go on, my son!"* in quite the way we often hear nowadays. I may be wrong, but I suspect the usage is particularly common in SE UK, and maybe significantly *less* common in America.

Comment: You could just refer to him as the "unnamed speaker" or "unknown speaker"...?  Or you could declare that, for the purposes of your paper, you will refer to him as "Fred".  (Although it could also be a her, in which case I'd recommend "Wilhelmina".)

Comment: Calling unrelated young men "son" is also common in the American South; consider the cartoon character [Foghorn Leghorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foghorn_Leghorn) as the stereotype. A Victorian might even stretch to use it to get the rhyme with _shun_.

Comment: However, "Come to my arms, my beamish boy!" suggests a close, affectionate relationship, and seems to establish that "my son" is literal.

Answer (score 1):

Only two stanzas of the poem "[Jabberwocky](https://books.google.com/books?id=i2MCAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22jabberwocky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aUNQVbWhHdHFogT4i4GIAw&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22jabberwocky%22&f=false)" have direct quotations in them—the rest is narration. Here are the two pieces that contain those quotations:

> "Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
>
> The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
>
> Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
>
> The frumious Bandersnatch!"
>
> ...
>
> "And hast thou slain the Jabberwock?
>
> Come to my arms, my beamish boy!
>
> O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!"
>
> He chortled in his joy.

These excerpts indicate that the speaker is male (owing to the line, "He chortled...") and that he has a relationship of some intimacy with the Jabberwock's future slayer, whom he refers to in the first stanza as "my son" and in the second as "my boy"). But beyond that, there is no clue as to the speaker's identity.

To distinguish the person who is responsible for the direct quotations from the narrator of the rest of the poem, I would call the former the "quoted speaker" and the later "the narrator," but I would also dedicate a sentence to explaining which parts of the poem belong to each personage.

Comment: Couldn't the one chortling in his joy also be the slayer/son/beamish boy?

Comment: @skymninge: I would characterize that interpretation as "not impossible." However, considering that the unidentified speaker has just been quoted as saying "Callooh! Callay!" in the preceding line—and considering that three lines of the four-line stanza are occupied by his remarks—I'm strongly inclined to attribute the chortling to that speaker.